# Possible to create new variable with new name upon button onclick?

Tags: javascript

I was wondering if it was possible to create a new variable when a button is pressed. For example: if I have a variable named enemy1 and the button is pressed, Can a variable named enemy2 be created? I'm sorry if this seems like a silly question.  I wanted to create a for loop where I can define a variable thats name changes depending on 'i'.

Comment: Sounds like a good place to use an array.

Comment: Variables are created by declaring them with `var` etc. Variables are not created dynamically, nor referenced dynamically by name. That is not how JS works. Probably what you want is to add a **property** to some object with the new name.

Answer (score 0):

Probably best to use an Array (adding new values on click) or Object (adding new keys on click). I think you should use an Array, so here is an example:

```js
const enemies = [];

class Enemy {
   speak () {
      return 'COME AT ME BRO!!!';
   }
}

document.querySelector('#createEnemy').addEventListener('click', function(event) {
   const enemy = new Enemy();
   enemies.push(enemy);
   console.log(enemies.length, 'enemies say', enemy.speak());
}, false);
```

```html
<button id="createEnemy">Create Enemy</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not require dynamic variable, instead you need one variable that would contain dynamic size (dynamic number of enemies). Following is the code you need. [**Here you can see demo**](https://plnkr.co/edit/c3SgfHcDV0RKL891yHXe?p=preview)

```
    <button id='createEnemy' onclick='addEnenemy()'>Add Enenmy</button>
    <div id='enemiesContainer'> </div> 
    <script>
        var enemies = [];    
        var enemyDiv = document.getElementById('enemiesContainer');
        function addEnenemy() {
           var newEnenmy = 'enemy'+(enemies.length+1);
           enemies.push(newEnenmy);
           //following will show it in your page
           enemyDiv.innerHTML = enemyDiv.innerHTML + '<br/><label>'+newEnenmy+'</label>'; 
           console.log(enemies); //shows in console
        }
    </script>
```